# How to insert date in SQL date type column?

Tags: sql

I have a table with date type column.

[image]

I am trying to insert date in it:

[image]

But I get an error:

[image]

Please give me to make the correct query to put the date

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Stop spamming the tags. Your error message indicates you are using an Oracle database.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: comon .. why you put -1 on that post? let me know? All people learn new things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy fix::**

```
INSERT INTO t(dob) VALUES(DATE '2015-12-17');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an Oracle question based on the [ORA-01843 error message](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01843_not_a_valid_month.htm), the problem appears to be in the date formatting as the error suggests.

In the provided example does the date '6-3-2012' mean '3 March 2012' or 'June 6, 2012?' The answer lies within the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119) parameter.

Out of the box, the Oracle date format is DD-MON-RR. So your corrected date format is either '03-MAR-12' or '06-JUN-12.' If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT has not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Never try to insert a string into a date column! If you have a string, use the `to_date` function with an explicit date format (and use 4 digit dates).

Relying on `nls_date_format` to implicitly convert your strings is just asking for trouble (like you just did), it can very easily change, even some apps will change it themselves.

The date literal (`date '2015-12-17'` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) always uses the same date format so that might be okay for ad hoc statements but you need to be aware that it is literal by name and literal by nature. They don't support bind variables so you will end up writing unshareable SQL to chew up your shared pool.